# My scheduled workflows aren't running on GitHub

Tags: github, yaml

I'm trying to set up a scheduled workflow on github, to run either every day or every minute.  I've tried everything and have read everything but can't seem to find any issues.  I currently have an empty repo, with .github/workflows containing main.yaml, which has :

```
name: Scheduled Workflow

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/5 * * * *'  # This cron expression triggers the workflow every 5 minutes

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Add your desired actions or commands here that you want to run every 5 minutes
      - name: Your Action
        run: |
          echo "This workflow runs every 5 minutes."
```

It's been there for days, shows up under actions, but has never run.  What am I doing wrong???  I assume there's something I didn't do on the GitHub end

I've tried really everything

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons which could explain why your workflow is not running.

### Possible issue 1: Your workflow was manually disabled

1. Go to your Github repository and click on the `Actions` tab.
2. In the left sidebar, you should see a list of all workflows in the current branch listed under `All Workflows`.
3. Click on the name of your workflow:

[image]

4. If your workflow was disabled you will see a yellow box in saying This workflow was disabled manually:

[image]
5. Click on `Enable Workflow` to enable it.

### Possible issue 2: You exceeded the usage limits of Github Actions

If you are the Free plan of Github, you are limited to 2000 minutes per month in a private repository.
For the latest information on the limits, see:

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/usage-limits-billing-and-administration
- https://docs.github.com/en/billing/managing-billing-for-github-actions/about-billing-for-github-actions

### Possible issue 3: Your CRON job schedule is invalid

Ensure that your CRON schedule is valid, taking into consideration the minimum schedule by Github:

> In order to provide a more reliable experience, we’ve set the minimum time period for scheduled runs to 5 minutes. A schedule of * * * * * which would previously run every minute will now run every five minutes.
>
> Reference: https://github.blog/changelog/2019-11-01-github-actions-scheduled-jobs-maximum-frequency-is-changing/

You can use https://crontab.guru/ to check your cron schedule.

### Debugging

If you are not facing any of the above issues, try manually triggering your workflow by adding `workflow_dispatch` to your workflow:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 * * * *" #  run every hour
```

Then, in the Actions tab, trigger your workflow as shown:
[image]